# Not able to make Listview items clickable

Tags: android, listview

I am not able to make my list view clickable.I have tried all the given solutions for same type of questions and had tried to change focusable and 
focusableintouchmode values to both true and false.

Sometimes it works (i.e text in listview gets clicked) after i click the button 10/12 times.
Below are my xml and java files.
I have also attached the screenshot of logcat when my row number 9 got clicked after i pressed it more than 20 times.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aeqii.png)
Please help..

> Activity_card.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rlLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.hppc.business.Card">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvUsers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> entry1.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="13dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

    <linearlayout>.....</linearlayout>
</linearLayout>
```

> card.java

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Card.this, Manual.class);
        Log.i("HelloListView", "You clicked Item: " + id + " at position:" + position);
        Log.e("YESSSS",Integer.toString(position));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: try delete ` android:clickable="true"` in your entry1.xml

Comment: remove last four lines from your listview xml- ie. clickable,focusable ,focusable in touchmode and especially  descendantFocusability

Comment: @JozefDochan　Thanks a lot man. It worked

Answer (score 0):

you have to make your list view focusable:

```
           android:focusable="true"
           android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: Thanks for help man.I had already tried this before but it didnt worked for me.Removing clickable in entry1.xml did.